# how to use sparql query in JSP for rdf over MySql database

Tags: jsp, rdf, sparql, ontology, sesame

Context:

I have deployed Sesame workbench server in "Glass fish server" (netbeans) and uploaded my ontology in "MySql RDF store".
Now I can see some tables created in my MySql database (connected to netbeans).. , and even some garbage kind of values inside it ( unlike export view in sesame-rdf workbench).

Problem:

Now may I know how to use sparql in a JSP page to query the values from the database,..like querying mysql rdf repository from sparql endpoint in Sesame workbench?

Comment: Duplicate of this question at http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/13003/how-to-use-sparql-in-a-jsp-page-to-query-the-values-mysql-rdf-repository-from-sparql-endpoint-in-sesame-workbench

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sesame Repository API from Java/JSP to connect to your database and do (SPARQL) queries over it. See [chapter 8 of the Sesame user manual](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/users/ch08.html) and/or see the [Repository API javadoc](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/api/).

Comment: That doesnt tell me how to use it from a JSP page..!!

Comment: JSP is *Java* Server Pages. I have given you a pointer to a Java API. It shouldn't be too hard to put these two together, right? Give it a try and if you get stuck, feel free to ask.